# Instagram intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open a new activity after my login activity(Instagram API).
The Login API is working well but i have just copy/paste the code and not really get what is going on.

So this is my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    setWidgetReference();
    bindEventHandlers();

    mApp = new InstagramApp(this, Constants.CLIENT_ID,
            Constants.CLIENT_SECRET, Constants.CALLBACK_URL);
    mApp.setListener(new InstagramApp.OAuthAuthenticationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // tvSummary.setText("Connected as " + mApp.getUserName());
            btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");

            //My Intent starts here

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("username", InstagramApp.TAG_USERNAME); 
            Login.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();

            //userInfoHashmap = mApp.
            mApp.fetchUserName(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String error) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    if (mApp.hasAccessToken()) {
        // tvSummary.setText("Connected as " + mApp.getUserName());
        btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");
        llAfterLoginView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mApp.fetchUserName(handler);

    }

}
```

I try to catch the Username in my MainActivity with this also (onCreate):

```
//INTENT
TextView tvUserName = findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra("username"); 
tvUserName.setText(username);
```

getting errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Specifically, what is the error message of "getting errors" and what line does it point to?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference - is the error

Answer (score 0):

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void TextView.setText(CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

This means you are attempting to call `setText(CharSequence)` on a `null` `TextView`.

If you look at your code, you can see you're calling it here.

```
//INTENT
TextView tvUserName = findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra("username"); 
tvUserName.setText(username);  // <--- this line is your issue
```

Now, the question is why is `tvUserName` `null`? Perhaps your layout doesn't include `R.id.tvUserName`, it's hard to tell from just this.

But that should help you figure out the issue.